# Python raising _ExpectedFailure for unittests with @unittest.expectedFailure

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have two systems running the same set of Django unittests. Some of the tests use the `@unittest.expectedFailure` decorator.

On one system, these are running fine and reporting at the end of the test run `OK (expected failures=10, unexpected successes=2)`.

On the other system, the same tests error, but raise `_ExpectedFailure` and `_UnexpectedSuccess` without tracebacks.

Has anyone seen this behavior before? Is it a configuration issue? Both systems are running Python 2.7, Django 1.3, and have unittest and unittest2 installed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the problem and I got it to work by deleting the /usr/local/lib/python2.7 and then reinstalling everything from scratch.

The reason for this I believe is that python may not have cleared it's python object and cache files(*.pyc, *.pyo) from it's working directory. That is, not YOUR project's directory but where python actually runs from.

Not sure if that's it but it worked for me!!