# expectedFailure is being counted as an error instead of as passed

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

I'm using `expectedFailure` because there is a bug that I want to record that I can't fix right now, but want to come back to it in the future. My understanding of `expectedFailure` is that it would count the test as passed but in the summary say that there were x number of expected failures (similar to how it works with skipped tets).

However, when I run my test suite I get the following:

```
$ ./manage.py test eav.QueryTest
Creating test database for alias 'default'...
.EE
======================================================================
ERROR: test_q_object_with_exclude (eav.tests.managers.QueryTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
_ExpectedFailure

======================================================================
ERROR: test_q_objects_unioned (eav.tests.managers.QueryTest)
----------------------------------------------------------------------
_ExpectedFailure

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 1.095s

FAILED (errors=2)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

I'm not sure if this lies with Django's test runner or something I'm doing wrong.

```
@unittest.expectedFailure
def test_q_object_with_exclude(self):
    # Everyone except Bob
    q_set = eav_m.Process.objects.exclude(
        Q(eav__details__city__contains='Y'))
    self.assertEqual(q_set.count(), 4)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your understanding of `expectedFailure`is right. Your problem is that those tests don't fail they raise an exception which is not the same as failing.

The decorator you are looking for is `skip`.

Comment: @JonathanHartley Not really. Tests fail in 2 ways. If they fail because some assert failed then that is status "FAIL" but if there is a crash like an exception raised, then that is status "ERROR". expectedFailure means that you expect a test to fail but it doesn't mean you were expecting it to crash.

Comment: No.
For TDD, UnexpectedFailure is a great way to let you know that your product code now satisfies the tests, without filling the reports with red. Using Skip basically sends the message that a test is flakey, or that there is no plan to fix the test or the product code soon, hopefully it's the latter. My only gripe, is that the decorators are actually "configuration", and in cases where inter-op with different environments is needed, they start to bleed your environment and product inter-op pains into your test code.

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5809333/python-raising-expectedfailure-for-unittests-with-unittest-expectedfailure) because this is not the right behaviour. A test with `expectedFailure` decorator [should not be counted as a failure](http://docs.python.org/library/unittest.html#unittest.expectedFailure) if the test fails.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I haven't tried rebuilding everything from scratch yet. However, I did run `sudo find /opt -type f -regex .*\.pyc -delete` on the theory that maybe there were compiled pyc files causing the problem. Unfortunately that didn't solve the problem.