# python 3.4 unittest fails despite expectedFailure on class

Tags: python, python-3.4, python-unittest

The `unittest.expectedFailure` decorator seems to have changed behaviour between Python 3.3 and 3.4 but I could not find any documentation about that change.
The issue is that the following leads to a test failure with Python 3.4.1 but does not with Python 2.7 or 3.3 (all on a debian system):

```
import unittest

@unittest.expectedFailure
class TestA(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_me(self):
        raise Exception('no')

unittest.main()
```

Note that this is just a short example script demonstrating the issue. In the actual test suite I have I can't simply check for an exception but rely on expectedFailure to make certain tests pass under certain circumstances.

Comment: Documentations in all three versions explicitly speak about marking a "test" with this decorator, not a test case. Seems that you've been relying on some undocumented accidental bug/feature. Also, failing is not the same as raising an exception. Refer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8493450/expectedfailure-is-being-counted-as-an-error-instead-of-as-passed

Comment: @BaroszKP: https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html#skipping-tests-and-expected-failures explicitly mentions skipping whole classes and lists `expectedFailure` with the other decorators for skipping. The code I'm testing (currently) throws an exception at C++ level which is passed down via boost and I consider this a failure.

Comment: @ozbob No, only skipping is mentioned in the context of whole test cases. The only part about `expectedFailure`: "In addition, it supports marking **a test** as a “expected failure,” ..." (emphasis mine). Further code examples also show only `skip` in test case  and test context, and `expectedFailure` only in a single test context.

Comment: @BartoszKP Hmm, my understanding is that `expectedFailure` is a special case for skipping and I don't see why skips should support classes and expected failures shouldn't. Also, in the list of decorators on that page _all_ decorators are explained in terms of tests only.

Comment: @ozbob No, on that page it says: "...and even whole classes of tests" for description of skipping. Also code examples with `skip` decorators cover test classes, not only test methods (see the third yellow block). I also don't see a particular reason for this difference, yet that's what the docs say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**It was a regression bug** [#21112: Python 3.4 regression: unittest.expectedFailure no longer works on TestCase subclasses](https://bugs.python.org/issue21112) in Python **3.4.0 to 3.4.3**, because unittest has been hard refactored in 3.4, fixed in 3.4.4 (v3.4.4rc1 by commit [ed599b7](https://github.com/python/cpython/commit/ed599b7c84ee))